# Value inside array changes

Tags: c, game-development

I am currently trying to build a simple snake program. For some reason a value inside an array changes. I have tried finding the answer to why online, as well as searching in the code. If anyone knows why it does this or how to fix it help would be much appreciated

```
#include "hardware.h"
#include "paint.h" // Include the library of paint functions
#include "snake.h" // Include the library of snake functions

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Set paint's size parameters to be equal to the snake ones
const int NCOLS = X_SIZE;
const int NROWS = Y_SIZE;

// Variables for game speed
#define START_WAIT 0.5 //
#define SPEEDUP_FACTOR 0.9

**Game.c**

int main()
{
  snake_t snakey;

  apple_t appley;
  appley.x = 12;
  appley.y = 12;

  int world[NROWS][NCOLS];

  snake_init(&snakey);
  world_field(world, &appley, &snakey);
  image_print(world);
  return 0;
}
```

**Snake.h**

```
#include "paint.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifndef __SNAKE_H__
#define __SNAKE_H__

// For snake we define the size by these macros
// Here the two dimensions are called x and y
#define X_SIZE 80 // Horizontal size, including walls
#define Y_SIZE 20 // Vertical size, including walls

typedef struct
{
    int x, y;
} apple_t;

typedef enum
{
    UP,
    RIGHT,
    DOWN,
    LEFT
} dir_t;

typedef struct
{
    int x[(X_SIZE - 2) * (Y_SIZE - 2)];
    int y[(X_SIZE - 2) * (Y_SIZE - 2)];
    int length;
    dir_t dir;
} snake_t;

void world_field(int world[Y_SIZE][X_SIZE], apple_t *apple, snake_t *snake);

void snake_init(snake_t *snake);


void world_field(int world[Y_SIZE][X_SIZE], apple_t *apple, snake_t *snake)
{
    for (int row = 0; row <= Y_SIZE; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= X_SIZE; col++)
            world[row][col] = GRASS;
    }

    add_rectangle(world, WALL, 0, 0, X_SIZE - 1, Y_SIZE);

    world[snake->y[0]][snake->x[0]] = SNAKE_HEAD;

    for (int i = 0; i < snake->length; i++)
    {
        world[snake->y[i]][snake->x[i]] = SNAKE_BODY;
        printf("Snake X 0: %d\nSnake Y 0: %d\nSnake X 1: %d\nSnake Y 1: %d\n", snake->x[0], snake->y[0], snake->x[1], snake->y[1]);
    }
}

void snake_init(snake_t *snake)
{
    snake->dir = RIGHT;
    snake->length = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < ((X_SIZE - 2) * (Y_SIZE - 2)); i++)
    {
        snake->x[i] = 90;
        snake->y[i] = 90;
    }
    snake->x[0] = 40;
    snake->x[1] = 39;
    snake->y[0] = 10;
    snake->y[1] = 10;
    printf("X koordinate 0: %d\nY koordinate 0: %d\n X koordinate 1: %d\n Y koordinate 1: %d\n\n\n\n", snake->x[0], snake->y[0], snake->x[1], snake->y[1]);
}


#endif
```

From the `snake_init()` function I am getting the output
X koordinate 0: 40
Y koordinate 0: 10
X koordinate 1: 39
Y koordinate 1: 10
From the `world_field()` function however, I am getting the output
Snake X 0: 46
Snake Y 0: 10
Snake X 1: 46
Snake Y 1: 10

Comment: A debugger can break on value change. Also you can enable ASAN & UBSAN to catch UB that could lead to this.

Comment: Generally, when you have the loop condition `<=` when iterating over an array, you're probably wrong. Which is the case here. You go out of bounds of your arrays in `world_field`, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: On another note, `NCOLS` or `X_SIZE`? While they are the same value, there's no definite connection between these two symbols which makes the code harder to read and understand.

Comment: You should also not define (implement) functions in a header file. Only *declare* the functions, then define them in a separate source file.

Comment: Oh and by the way, all symbols beginning with two leading underscores (like e.g. `__SNAKE_H__`) are *reserved*. You should never define such symbols yourself (as macros, variables, functions etc.).

Comment: It would make the code a bit more readable if you defined a macro `#define SNAKE_MAX_LENGTH ((X_SIZE - 2) * (Y_SIZE  - 2))`. Also, in `world_field()`, you set one of the `world[x][y]` values to `SNAKE_HEAD` and then immediately change it to `SNAKE_BODY`, so you end up with a headless snake.

Comment: The call `add_rectangle(world, WALL, 0, 0, X_SIZE - 1, Y_SIZE);` looks wrong although we have not seen its source. Are the last two arguments (`X_SIZE - 1` and `Y_SIZE`) supposed to be coordinates? If so, `Y_SIZE` is out of range.

Comment: Prefer symbolic constants to `const` variables.  The former creates compile time sized arrays when used as dimensions while the latter are vla which doesn't support initialization.